# Nuxt js custum js file not loading

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

My custom js file is not loading. am getting the following error

*GET http://localhost:62113/assets/custum/js0.1/accordin.js net:: ERR_ABORTED 404 (Not Found)*

```
export default {
    head(){
        return{
            title:'Docs',
             script: [
                { src: '../assets/custum/js0.1/accordin.js' }
                ],
            meta:[
                {
                    hid:'description',
                    name:'description',
                    content:''
                }
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: can you try ~/assets/custum/js0.1/accordin.js

Comment: It doesn't work, at this point, I will just load it trough CDN

Comment: ah sorry, just keep your js file into static folder, then just change the path where static folder treat as a root.